# Calling EventMachine.popen with local handler

Tags: ruby, subprocess, eventmachine

Ruby's [EventMachine.popen](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#M000491) seems to require a global module-based handler. This is an overkill, because it seems impossible to have local handlers, eg:

```
def local_run(cmd)
  q = EventMachine::Queue.new
  module Handler
    def receive_data data
      q.push data
    end
  end
  EM.system(cmd, Handler)
  q
end
```

The above code wouldn't run; ruby complains `module definition in method body (SyntaxError)`

Is there a way to define local handlers for `EM.system`?

All I care about is being able to run local commands asynchronously, and return a queue that would contain the STDOUT data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use any of the EM commands without using EM.run {}. Nothing would happen, no commands sent, no data received, no callbacks fired.

Most EM code can use a module, it can also use a class, or it can be defined when you call the function.

You could do something like:

```
EM.popen("ls -l") do |p|
  def p.receive_data(data)
   puts data
  end
end
```

Which should do the same thing (*but* cannot accept a custom argument such as the queue in your question).

You should also be able to do (this time, with queue):

```
class Foo < EM::Connection
  def initialize(q)
    @q = q
  end
  def receive_data(data)
    @q.push data
  end
end
EM.popen("ls -l", Foo, EventMachine::Queue.new)
```

Comment: I did not say anything about not using EM.run, but good to know that there is a way to define handler functions locally. Unfortunately, it seems that your `receive_data` cannot access variables from the parent scope. See https://gist.github.com/1498155#comments ... I never had this problem with any other EM async handlers. For this reason, I cannot use this approach in my code.

Comment: Finally, your second example using `class` doesn't work at all (remember, I do all of this from inside a **function**) as that leads to `class definition in method body (SyntaxError)`. What I mean by "local" - in the question - is the **function**'s local scope.

Comment: Ah, then I didn't interpret the 'Without an EventMachine loop' comment above correctly. Sounded like you were not planning on using EM.run.

Comment: Why define the class in the function? Why not just define it as a class? If you want access to the q you can pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: "Why not just define it as a class?" - that's what I ended up doing (and passed `q` as a parameter, so it gets passed to `initialize`), but *ideally* I wish to make use of anonymously-defined code blocks (as hinted in your gist comment). I'll accept your 2nd solution as answer.

Comment: Yea, looks like you can't do it anonymous. Looking at the EM, if you're using an anonymous code block the class that's created is EM::Connection, this defines initialize as the class needs to be created to get passed to the block.  So, initialize is already executed but you can override any of the other methods.